# trouble running query on Access DB in asp classic

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to run a query on my database and I keep getting an error `80004005` on the execute but do not know why?

```vb
Set adconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
adconn.Open "justlistit_changes"

Set sqlgetad1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
sqlgetad1.ActiveConnection = adconn
sqlgetad1.commandtext = "Select * from ads where county = '" & selcounty & "' and where position='1'"
sqlgetad1.Prepared = true
sqlgetad1.execute
adconn.Close
```

The query works fine when I just use the `county` parameter but will not work once I try to use `position` anywhere in the query, even just by itself.  I have tried hardcoding and using variables but nothing works, please help.

Comment: what sort of field is position?  Try `position=1` rather than `position='1'`

Comment: So you use the `ADODB.Command` object but don't bother to parametrise your query? What is the point in that?

Comment: Do you have the full detail of the error?

Comment: I was having trouble running other queries when using parameters so i scrapped them all together.  I did not build this site, I just took it over and I have never done classic asp before

Comment: @adgoodso23 That's your problem right there then. `ADODB.Command` is the correct approach, your predecessor was on the right track. As for `"Select * from ads where county = '" & selcounty` this is documented bad practice and leaves you open to SQL Injection.

Comment: What is this line doing? - `adconn.Open "justlistit_changes"` The `ADODB.Connection` `.Open()` method expects a valid connection string which this is not. My guess is your `justlistit_changes` is a variable that defines a connection string not a literal string `"justlistit_changes"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update**
>
> The cause is `position` is a ANSI 92 reserved word in Microsoft Access - see [ACC2002: Error with ANSI-92 Reserved Words When SQL Server Compatibility Syntax (ANSI 92) Is Enabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287417)
>
> To workaround this simply encapsulate your field in square brackets `[]` *(Updated my example below)*.
>
> ```
> [position] = ?
> ```

---

> **Update**
>
> Looks like the error your reporting has nothing to do with your code.
>
> - [80004005 Errors](http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html)

---

Your using `ADODB.Command` but setting variables in the `CommandText` which bypasses the protection using `ADODB.Command` gives you when executing Parametrised Queries.

Try this;

```vb
Dim sqlgetad1, rs

Set sqlgetad1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With sqlgetad1
  'Assuming justlistit_changes is your connection string variable.
  .ActiveConnection = justlistit_changes
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  '******** Avoid any clashes with ANSI 92 reserved words ********
  .CommandText = "Select * from ads where [county] = ? and [position] = ?"
  .Prepared = true
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@county", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100))
  'Assuming your position field is actually a numeric value.
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@position", adInteger, adParamInput, 4))
  .Parameters("@county").Value = selcounty
  .Parameters("@position").Value = 1
  Set rs = .Execute()
End With
```

If your `position` field is not an numeric replace with

```vb
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@position", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10))
.Parameters("@position").Value = "1"
```

---

If you have trouble with the ADO named constants like `adCmdText` for example have a look at [how to use METADATA to import DLL constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26776169/692942).

Comment: Ive tried this and i still get the error '80004005'
/wwwroot/display.asp, line 154.  line 154 being the Execute command

Comment: Its something to do with the position field in the database.  I made a new field called 'adpos' and its working fine.  I guess I'll just use the new field.

Comment: @adgoodso23 How can it be working, `adconn.Open "justlistit_changes"` isn't a valid connection string, what code are you actually using?

Comment: @adgoodso23 Scrap that `POSITION` is a ANSI 92 reserved word that will be the issue. See [Update](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26788713/4).

Answer (score 0):

Loose the second "where":

```
"Select * from ads where county = '" & selcounty & "' and where position='1'"
```

==>

```
"Select * from ads where county = '" & selcounty & "' and position='1'"
```