# ASP Classic parameter error

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I'm trying to run an parameterized query to the database:

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

QUERY = ""
QUERY = QUERY & "INSERT INTO ORGBHVEmergencydocument(documentDate, version, LocationID, note, title) "
QUERY = QUERY & "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "

cmd.ActiveConnection = objCon
cmd.CommandText = QUERY

set paramDate = cmd.CreateParameter("@datum", adDate, adParamInput, , datum)
set paramVersion = cmd.CreateParameter("@version", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, version)
set paramLocation = cmd.CreateParameter("@Location", adInteger, adParamInput, , locationID)
set paramNote = cmd.CreateParameter("@note", adVarChar, adParamInput, , note)
set paramTitle = cmd.CreateParameter("@title", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, title)

cmd.Parameters.Append paramDate    
cmd.Parameters.Append paramVersion    
cmd.Parameters.Append paramLocation    
cmd.Parameters.Append paramNote    
cmd.Parameters.Append paramTitle   

cmd.execute
```

When I execute this I get the error:
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

which point to the line: 'set paramDate'

the variable datum is set in the beginning as: cDate(documentdate) and in the database the documentDate is a Datetime. So what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you binding to the ADO typelib or using one of the ADO includes? If your not the `ad*` enums will be undefined

Comment: Indeed, I looked over this thanks

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26776169/692942