# Setting CursorType with ADODB.Command.Execute

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, sql-injection, adodb

Is there any way to set the `CursorType` for an `ADODB.RecordSet` which I obtain from `ADODB.Command.Execute`?

I know that it is possible if I do:

```
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open(cmd)
```

However, I currently use `Command.Execute` with the `Parameters` parameter, which automatically handles variant-arrays of `?` parameters for safe interpolation. Therefore using `RecordSet.Open` does not appear to be an option.

Specifically, my code currently looks like:

```
function ExecuteSQL(conn, sql, args)
    set ExecuteSQL_CmdObj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    ExecuteSQL_CmdObj.CommandType = adCmdText
    ExecuteSQL_CmdObj.CommandText = sql
    ExecuteSQL_CmdObj.ActiveConnection = conn
    if Ubound(args) = -1 then
        set ExecuteSQL = ExecuteSQL_CmdObj.Execute
    else
        set ExecuteSQL = ExecuteSQL_CmdObj.Execute(,args)
    end if
end function
```

If I want to maintain this same API, but *also* control `CursorType`, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: An alternate formulation of this question would be: Is there a way to automatically handle variant-arrays of `?` parameters with `RecordSet.Open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as far as I've been able to determine is that this is impossible with `ADODB.Command.Execute`, but it's possible with `ADODB.RecordSet.Open` using `ADODB.Command.Parameters`:

```vbs
function CreateSQLParameter(arg)
    set param = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")

    select TypeName(arg)
        case "String"
            param.Type = adVarChar
            param.Size = Len(CStr(arg))
            param.Value = CStr(arg)
        case "Integer"
            param.Type = adInteger
            param.Value = CLng(arg)
        case "Double"
            param.Type = adDouble
            param.Value = CDbl(arg)
        case else
            ' 13 is the "Type Mismatch" error code
            Err.Raise(13,,, "Type '" & TypeName(arg) "' is not handled. Please add support for it to CreateSQLParameter")
    end select

    set CreateSQLParameter = param
end function

function CreateSQLCommand(sql, args)
    set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    'From http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_comm_commandtype.asp.
    'adCmdText is for some reason undefined in our scope.
    cmd.CommandType = 1
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    for i = Lbound(args) to Ubound(args)
        set param = CreateSQLParameter(args(i))
        cmd.Parameters.Append(param)
    next

    set CreateSQLCommand = cmd
end function

function ExecuteSQL(conn, sql, args)
    set cmd = CreateSQLCommand(sql, args)
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    rs.Open(cmd, conn)

    set ExecuteSQL = rs
end function
```

Comment: Where is the `CursorType` set in this?

Comment: The named constants are undefined because VBScript doesn't know about ADO's Type Library you have to tell it - See [A: Passing Parameters to a Stored Procedure using ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26776169/692942) *(section about `METADATA`)*.

Comment: That degree of encapsulation is just not required. It would work exactly the same way if you setup a command added the parameter using `.Append(.CreateParameter(...))` in the context of the `ADODB.Command` and passed it the required values and executed using `rs.Open()`. The issue however is like [@ansgar-wiechers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) has [pointed out already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134395/setting-cursortype-with-adodb-command-execute#comment67539996_40134395) even if you set the `CursorType` it will be ignored.

Comment: Where is the cursortype?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and easy way to accomplish this:

```
    Dim arrErrorCode(1,1)
    Dim ArrayRS
    
    On Error Resume Next
                
    Set rsGetIPInfo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set oCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
                
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM RemoteIPInfo WHERE RemoteIP_ID = ?"
                
    oCMD.ActiveConnection = oConnGlobal
    oCMD.CommandText = sSQL
    oCMD.CommandType = adCmdText
    oCMD.CommandTimeout = 120
    oCMD.Parameters.Append oCMD.CreateParameter("@RemoteIP_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,RemoteIP_ID)
    
    rsGetIPInfo.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rsGetIPInfo.Open oCMD, ,adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    GetIPInfoCount = rsGetIPInfo.RecordCount
    
    If Not rsGetIPInfo.BOF And Not rsGetIPInfo.EOF Then
        ArrayRS = rsGetIPInfo.GetRows()
    End If
                
    arrRowNumberIPInfo = Ubound(ArrayRS, 1)  
                
    If Err.Number > 0 Then 
        arrRowNumberErrorCode = Ubound(arrErrorCode, 1)  
        Response.Write("Error Number: ") & Err.Number & "<br>"
        Response.Write("Error Description: ") & Err.Description & "<br>"
        Response.Write("Error Source: ") & Err.Source & "<br>"
        Err.Raise 13
        Response.End
                    
    End If
    
    rsGetIPInfo.Close
    Set rsGetIPInfo = Nothing
    
    On Error Goto 0
```