# Can't pass a string to a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

Here's my stored procedure...

```sql
alter PROCEDURE ReplyToEmailConfirmation 
    @uniqueKey varchar(36)
AS
BEGIN

Print 'Hello World!'
END
```

Here's the code...

```vb
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = getConfigValue("ASPClassicConnectionString")
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[ReplyToEmailConfirmation]"

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@uniqueKey", adVarChar, adParamInput, 36, "dc8d8bfd-ea3a-4ad9-9f2d-92831eb2655a")

End With

cmd.Execute
```

Here's the error...

> ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another.

How do I get this to work? The intention is to use `adGUID`, but I figured I'd try `adVarChar` to narrow down the error.

Comment: seems like you can automatically fill in the parameter info from the stored procedure with `.Parameters.Refresh` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676516

Comment: @Slai don't do that it requires an extra trip to the server to pull the parameter information, not recommended.

Comment: You are missing the `Size` parameter from your `CreateParameter()` method try `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@uniqueKey", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100)`. Also try telling ADODB that you are executing a Stored Procedure by setting `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't include `adovbs.inc` for the `adCmdStoredProc`, `adVarChar` and `adGUID` constants. Doh.

Comment: Are you using this in Classic ASP? VBScript doesn't support includes, if you are consider using [METADATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765838/passing-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure-using-asp/26776169#26776169) approach.

Comment: Yes, Classic ASP. By include, I mean... `<!--#include virtual="/include/adovbs.asp"-->`.

Comment: Would be helpful to have the [tag:asp-classic] tag in the question so we understand the context. If I'd realised would have included information about using `METADATA` in my answer.

Comment: That tag is on the question! Or did you add it?

Comment: In which other environment might I be using VBScript and ADO?

Comment: There are plenty, VBScript is used as a scripting language for a lot of different hosts. But you can most commonly call it using `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` from most Windows OS based computers. Yes I added the tag you can see [the revision here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40477942/6).

Answer (score 4):

If you [read the documentation for `CreateParameter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) all becomes clear;

> *If you specify a variable-length data type in the Type argument, you must either pass a Size argument or set the Size property of the Parameter object before appending it to the Parameters collection; otherwise, an error occurs.*

As you are passing a `VARCHAR` which is a *"variable-length"* data type you have to specify `Size` when calling `CreateParameter()`.

```vb
Dim cmd

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    'Let the cmd deal with the connection.
    .ActiveConnection = getConfigValue("ASPClassicConnectionString")
    .CommandText = "[ReplyToEmailConfirmation]"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@uniqueKey", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100))
    .Parameters("@uniqueKey") = "dc8d8bfd-ea3a-4ad9-9f2d-92831eb2655a"
End With
Call cmd.Execute()

'Tidy up memory
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Also included [`CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678358(v=vs.85).aspx) of `adCmdStoredProc` which tells ADO to interpret this command as a Stored Procedure call, without it the default is `adCmdUnknown` which means ADO has to attempt to workout what the command is, which however small adds an unnecessary overhead.

Also not a big fan of instantiating the `ADODB.Connection` object just to execute a `ADO.Command` object which then means you have to manage closing the `ADODB.Connection` yourself. Instead let the `ADODB.Command` do it for you, by passing a connection string letting it create the connection and destroy it itself. Assuming `getConfigValue("ASPClassicConnectionString")` returns a connection string you can pass it directly to `ActiveConnection` and the `ADODB.Command` will instantiate the connection and dispose of it.

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: Passing Parameters to a Stored Procedure using ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26776169/692942) *(Explains how to use `METADATA` to include Named Constants)*

Comment: I'd already tried the size parameter and it didn't work either. I've updated the question.

Comment: Also, I removed `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` because it seemed to be causing the same error.

Comment: In fact, if I remove the parameter from both ends, setting the command type results in this error.

Comment: @IanWarburton Yes as you have surmised you need the ADODB Named Constants defining either manually using `Const name = value` or using `METADATA` *(see link in answer)* to import the Type Library for your entire Web Application and never have to define them again.